# What is the cost of Unmortgaging Park Lane / Park Place in Monopoly?

Tags: monopoly

Properties of value x have mortgage value x/2 and unmortgage value 11x/20, for 27 of the properties this is an exact dollar value but Park Place is special.

Cost M$350, Mortgage M$175, unmortgage M$192.5. Half dollars don't exist and would never be useful EXCEPT in this case.

Is there an official ruling for the unmortgage cost of Park Lane? I've always played it as $193 but an argument came up when an opponent only had M$592 and wanted to put houses on Mayfair and Park Lane and unmortgage Park lane on the same turn, it made a difference of M$105 rent the next turn.

Answer (score 10):

You round up. So the unmortgage cost of Park Place is $193.

[The rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00114.pdf) for the electronic banking version of monopoly have this specifically listed in the mortgage rules.

page 12:

> **Repaying a mortgage**
>   You must pay the original mortgage amount plus 10% interest (**rounded up to the nearest 10,000**). Once the mortgage is repaid, turn the Title Deed card faceup.

emphasis mine.

In this version you start with $15Million instead of the normal $1500, so the nearest $10,000 is equivalent to $1 in other versions.